# Which complexity class does this number theory problem belong to?

Tags: ds.algorithms, complexity-classes, reductions, nt.number-theory, np-complete

'Given $a,b,c\in\Bbb N$, is there $x,y\in\Bbb N$, $ax^2+by=c$' is $\mathsf{NP}$-complete.

Which complexity class does 'Given $a,b,c\in\Bbb N$, is there $x,y\in\Bbb N$, $ax^2+by^2=c$' belong to?

Comment: Why is the first problem NP-complete?  A reference would be appreciated.  :)

Comment: @MichaelWehar, Quadratic Diophantine is NP-complete. I think it is even in Gary and Johnson.

Comment: It is AN8 in Garey and Johnson, page 250: Manders and Adleman, "NP-complete decision problems for binary quadratics",1978.

Comment: The existence of *rational* solutions is polynomially reducible to factoring, hence in $\mathrm{NP}\cap\mathrm{coNP}$: using the [Hasse principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_principle), it amounts to checking that the [Hilbert symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_symbol#Hilbert_symbols_over_the_rationals) $(a/c,b/c)_p=1$ for all primes $p\mid2abc$.

Comment: Note that (for either integer or rational solvability) you are unlikely to get anything better than factoring: already the special case $a=b=1$ (i.e., whether $c$ is a sum of two squares) asks whether all primes $p\equiv3\pmod4$ occur in $c$ with even multiplicity, and to the best of my knowledge, it’s not known how to test this more efficiently than factoring $c$; cf. http://mathoverflow.net/q/57981 .

Comment: Ah, now I finally found the post I was looking for: an equivalent question was already asked at http://mathoverflow.net/q/202037 , but didn’t receive very informative answers (note that the highest-voted answer is misleading: despite the wording, it applies only to solvability of the original problem in $\mathbb Q$, as in my first comment).

Comment: @EmilJeřábek What do you mean by 'rational' solutions? Are you implying problem is in $\mathsf{NP}\cap\mathsf{coNP}$ if $a,b,c\in\Bbb Z$ rather than in $\Bbb N$? I do not see why $a,b,c\in\Bbb N$ would affect a similar interpretation? May be your Hilbert symbol comment could be appropriate answer here?

Comment: Rational solution means solution with $x,y\in\mathbb Q$.

Comment: I am thinking if there are no-solutions over $\Bbb Q$, then there are no solutions over $\Bbb Z$. So it should be very close to being in $\mathsf{coNP}$ if not already in it.

Comment: Is corollary $4.4.19$ http://alozano.clas.uconn.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/490/2014/01/Curry_Thesis_May_2014.pdf relevant?

Comment: The trouble is with the converse inclusion: it can happen that the equation is solvable in $\mathbb Q$, but not in $\mathbb Z$, so solvability in $\mathbb Q$ is a different (and presumably easier) problem.

Answer (score 5):

Added later: As noted in the comments, the NP upper bound is trivial if a, b, and c are positive, as was asked.

Theorem 1.2 in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0611209) shows that deciding if a given diophantine equation in two variables has a solution is in NP.

Comment: I do not this is a good answer (it states the obvious).

Comment: @Arul : $\:$ Why is that obvious? $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: This seems to answer the question that was asked.  If you were intending further conditions, you need to include them in the question.

Comment: It is not at all obvious a priori that deciding that a solution to a diophantine equation exists is in NP. The solution itself is not a useful certificate. For example, the least solution may exponentially bigger than the coefficients.

Comment: @AndrásSalamon, it doesn't, the NP upper bound seems trivial when $a$ and $b$ are both nonnegative (so $x$ and $y$ are polynomially bounded by in $a$, $b$, and $c$). The real question is if it hard for NP.

Comment: @Kaveh: yes, but that is not what was asked.  Further, I presume a,b,c are given in binary, so x and y are only exponentially bounded in n?

Comment: @AndrásSalamon, Their _size_ are polynomially bounded in $n$. As I said, being in NP is trivial for the problem. The paper is talking about a more general case which the question is not about.